# Proximity Sensor Browser Support

Tags: android, iphone, html, browser, sensors

I haven't tracked down any browsers that support proximity sensors. Is anybody aware of any browser that supports access to proximity sensors?

Answer (score 0):

The only mobile browser I'm aware of with support for Proximity sensors will be the BB10 browser [using WebWorks](https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/apis/blackberry.sensors.html#.event%3adeviceproximity).  That said, [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-proximity-20121206/) went into *Last Call working draft* status today (ends January 24).  Hopefully we'll see some support in Android soon.